# Political Consultants on The West Wing

Tags: production, the-west-wing

Did 'The West Wing' use political consultants on the show much like procedural medical shows use doctors as consultants?

Or was the politics depicted in the show all based on research and Aaron Sorkin's past work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they did use some consultants.

[Lawrence O'Donnell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_O%27Donnell), [Eli Attie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eli_Attie), [Dee Dee Myers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dee_Dee_Myers), [Marlin Fitzwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlin_Fitzwater), [Patrick Caddell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Caddell), [Frank Luntz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Luntz), [Peggy Noonan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peggy_Noonan) and [Gene Sperling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Sperling) were the ones who contributed the most to the show.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_West_Wing#Realism)

Comment: Should be noted that many of these were more than just "consultants" who were called on - many were on the writing team and actively contributed to plots